# MailMessage, difference between Sender and From properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, system.net.mail

I've been using the `System.Net` namespace ever since we switched from .NET Framework 1.1 to the 3.5 framework, but there’s one thing that’s been puzzling me since. What's the difference between the `Sender` and the `From` properties in the `MailMessage` class?

Are they both the same, and if not is there a reason to use `Sender` together with `From`?

For example:

```
Using m As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    m.Sender = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com", "Name here")
    m.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com", "Name here")

    m.Subject = "Test"
    m.Body = "Test"

    Dim client As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mymailserver.com")
    client.Send(m)
End Using
```

Comment: In the case of the System.Net.Mail implementation there is no difference. When calling into SmtpTransport.SendMail it does this `message.Sender != null ? message.Sender : message.From`. The result is SmtpClient does not allow you to send distinct values for Sender and From

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Excerpt from the wiki on email:

Header fields:
The message header should include at least the following fields:

**From:** The e-mail address, and optionally the name of the author(s). In many e-mail clients not changeable except through changing account settings.

Also note that the "From:" field does not have to be the real sender of the e-mail message. One reason is that it is very easy to fake the "From:" field and let a message seem to be from any mail address. It is possible to digitally sign e-mail, which is much harder to fake, but such signatures require extra programming and often external programs to verify. Some ISPs do not relay e-mail claiming to come from a domain not hosted by them, but very few (if any) check to make sure that the person or even e-mail address named in the "From:" field is the one associated with the connection. Some ISPs apply e-mail authentication systems to e-mail being sent through their MTA to allow other MTAs to detect forged spam that might appear to come from them.

**Sender:** Address of the **actual sender** acting on behalf of the author listed in the From: field (secretary, list manager, etc.).

Details on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email

**For example gmail uses the from/sender fields to send emails from different email adresses than your gmail account (After verification).**

Answer (score 28):

I found [this](http://www.tectite.com/fmdoc/from_vs_sender.php) explanation to be pretty easy to understand (emphasis mine).

> One area in which there is quite a variety of operation is in the
>   concept of the From Address of an email and the Sender of the email.
>
> Some email servers will accept the From Address as being the Sender,
>   and some deduce the Sender automatically, and some require the Sender
>   to be specified explicitly.
>
> **In general, the Sender is the actual originator of the email message.
>   The From Address, in contrast, is simply a header line in the email
>   that may or may not be taken to mean anything.** The From Address can
>   often be left out completely. Spammers can easily spoof the From
>   Address. ISPs try to ensure that spammers cannot spoof the Sender.