# How do I assign a value to a MailMessage ReplyTo property?

Tags: .net, email

I want to set the ReplyTo value for a .NET MailMessage.

[MailMessage.ReplyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replyto(v=VS.100).aspx) Property:

> ReplyTo is obsoleted for this type. 
>   Please use ReplyToList instead which
>   can accept multiple addresses.

[MailMessage.ReplyToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist.aspx) Property:

> Gets or sets the list of addresses to
>   reply to for the mail message.

But, ReplyToList is ReadOnly.

I've tried to use the [MailMessage.Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headers.aspx) property like this:

```
mail.Headers.Add("Reply-To", "johndoe@example.com");
```

as described here: [System.Web.Mail, OH MY!](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/2.7.aspx)

But, that doesn't seem to work.

How do I set the value(s) of the MailMessage's ReadOnly property ReplyToList?

Comment: This is exactly why we need [**Warlords of Documentation**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered?cb=1) - This is infinitely more helpful than the MSDN page on [`MailMessage.ReplyToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`ReplyToList` is an instance of [MailAddressCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.aspx) which exposes [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.add.aspx) method.

To add a new address you can simply pass address as string

```
  message.ReplyToList.Add("john.doe@example.com");
```

Comment: Bah! That's just obtuse. Why not allow an assignment of a collection of `MailAddress`??

Comment: Note: You can pass a single string containing a comma-separated list of email addresses if necessary ;)

Answer (score 13):

I like the array init syntax, which will call Add() for you.

```
var msg = new MailMessage("noreply@example.com", mailTo) {
    Subject = "my important message",
    Body = this.MessageBody,
    ReplyToList = { mailTo } // array init syntax calls Add()
};
mailClient.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 9):

You cannot say

```
message.ReplyToList = new MailAddressCollection();
```

To create a new collection. However, adding to the *existing* collection is what you want to do.

```
message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("foo@bar.net"));
```

Answer (score 6):

My answer is not unlike the accepted answers already given. However, I felt it needed to be provided.

```
var fromEmail = new MailAddress("foobar@example.com", "Foo Bar");
var replyEmail = new MailAddress("foo@example.com", "Foo Example");
var msgEmail = new MailMessage { From = fromEmail };
msgEmail.ReplyToList.Add( replyEmail );
```

Comment: Simpler to do this: msgEmail.ReplyToList.Add("foobar@example.com, foo@example.com") ;

Answer (score 3):

I used the [MailMessage.Sender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.sender.aspx) property instead.

```
mail.Sender = new Mail.MailAddress("system@example.com");
mail.From = new Mail.MailAddress("johndoe@example.com", "John Doe");
```

More info: [MailMessage, difference between Sender and From properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668721/mailmessage-difference-between-sender-and-from-properties)

Answer (score 1):

```
MailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("johndoe@example.com, janedoe@example.com, xxxx@yyyy.com");
```

*Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads*

---

*I expect that it is also possible to optionally include "friendly name" using the above approach, probably using this format:* **Jon Doe `<jondoe@example.com`>**

*Refs.: 
https://askleo.com/why_are_email_addresses_sometimes_in_anglebrackets/,
https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/220563147-What-is-a-Friendly-From-name-and-address-, 
https://wordtothewise.com/2014/12/friendly-email-addresses/.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add list of ReplyTo Addresses  to ReplyToList by Add method :

```
            mail.Sender = new MailAddress(from, displayName);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from, displayName);
            mail.ReplyToList.Add("replyToAddress@host.com");
```