# changing name with email when sending emails

Tags: c#

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(email.From,
                                                      email.To,
                                                      email.Subject,
                                                      email.Body);
```

but i can not see name when i get email. I want that instead of "noreplay@domain.com" i will get name like  "Confirmation" or something else. Can i change email with name in from field in web.config?

```
<add key="ActivationUserFromEmail" value="'Confirmation' <noreplay@domain.com>" />
```

is not correct XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
message.From = new MailAddress("noreplay@domain.com", "Confirmation");
```

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx

Comment: To answer my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668721/mailmessage-difference-between-sender-and-from-properties