# MailMessage class C#

Tags: c#

Can anybody let me know what is the difference between:

1) From and Sender

These are properties of MailMessage class. Also there is property named Reply. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: This question answers your from/sender question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668721/mailmessage-difference-between-sender-and-from-properties

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from the wiki on email:

**Header fields:** The message header should include at least the following fields:

**From:** The e-mail address, and optionally the name of the author(s). In many e-mail clients not changeable except through changing account settings.

Also note that the "From:" field does not have to be the real sender of the e-mail message. One reason is that it is very easy to fake the "From:" field and let a message seem to be from any mail address. It is possible to digitally sign e-mail, which is much harder to fake, but such signatures require extra programming and often external programs to verify. Some ISPs do not relay e-mail claiming to come from a domain not hosted by them, but very few (if any) check to make sure that the person or even e-mail address named in the "From:" field is the one associated with the connection. Some ISPs apply e-mail authentication systems to e-mail being sent through their MTA to allow other MTAs to detect forged spam that might appear to come from them.

**Sender:** Address of the actual sender acting on behalf of the author listed in the From: field (secretary, list manager, etc.).

Details on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email

For example gmail uses the from/sender fields to send emails from different email adresses than your gmail account (After verification).

**ReplyTo** is obsoleted. Please use ReplyToList instead which can accept multiple addresses. It Gets or sets the ReplyTo address for the mail message. If you want to reply to a sent email then it will be sent to these addresses.

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer what is the difference between From and Sender.